# How does the processor understand which encoding scheme is used when it decodes different encoded data?

Tags: encoding

How does the processor understand which encoding scheme is used when it decodes different encoded data? For example, I have input 'A' from the keyboard - how does the processor figure out whether the encoding scheme for this data was ASCII or maybe UTF-8, etc?

Comment: Keyboards send scan codes, not characters. So you would probably benefit by focusing this question on one and not the other. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: What do you mean by scan codes?

Comment: The [data](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes.html) sent by a keyboard when a key is pressed or released. For example, the left shift key. (The term "scan" probably comes from a hardware implementation that would be/was of interest to electrical engineers.) This has nothing to do with character encodings.